# Python: Lifetime of module-global variables

Tags: python, global, lifecycle, cpython

I have a shared resource with high initialisation cost and thus I want to access it across the system (it's used for some instrumentation basically, so has to be light weight). So I created a module managing the setup and access to it. It does a lazy initialise of the resource and stores it in a module global variable. I then use functions of this module across the system to operate on the resource. 
- Now I am wondering whether (or how often) I will have to reinitialise the resource? 
- I know objects are garbage collected in CPython on (or better around) zero reference count, but is storing in an module counted as a reference, even if the module is not being executed at the moment?

Example with code: here we have the module, where _connect() is slow. I want to use report_safely() across my system and end up calling _connect() as seldom as possible.

```
__metrics = None


def _connect():
    global __metrics

    client = SomeSlowToSetUpClient()
    __metrics = SomeMetrics(client)
    client.connect()


def report_safely():
       if not __metrics:
           _connect()

       __metrics.execute_lightweight_code()
```

Comment: One question to ask is, are you sure that having this thing connected basically **at all times after the first connect** is a good idea?

Comment: Well, this thing is only firing UDP packets to a server so I don't see a problems with staying connected?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Objects that are no longer referenced are indeed garbage collected (they are deleted automatically when their reference count drops to 0).

A module global, however, will never have it's reference count drop to 0; once imported a module object (its namespace), lives in the `sys.modules` mapping. The namespace itself refers to your object.

In other words, your object lives on forever, until you either delete it from the module namespace, delete the module namespace itself (`del sys.modules['yourmodule']`) or your python script exits.

Comment: That sounds nice. Thank you Martijn! However now I wonder what script exits means. The context is a Django app and the modules importing this thing are executed in (celery) worker threads. Does that mean that the module gets executed on each worker thread termination, or does the lifetime of the parent count? I mean... I can import it somewhere in the spawning parent thread, but that sounds a bit jacky.

Comment: @Zakum: Celery workers import code only *once*, then run tasks in threads.

Comment: ... which means that I'm good, as long as celery is running. Grand, thanks a lot! (Will leave this thing open for a few more hours/opinions just in case, but it looks like you have a strong claim for accepted answer)

Answer (score 0):

If the module containing the global is in scope from the start of your execution to the end then the globals will be to.  Might be cleaner to use a class instance though.

Comment: A Java like Singleton was my first idea as well, but that seemed quite unpythonic since I had only @classmethods and classvariables in that thing. Plus, same question with garbage collection arises with a Singleton class.